# How can I get the callee in PHP?

Tags: php, language-features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caller function in PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5)

I would like to know from where a global function or public method is being called. I guess I could do it by inspecting debug_backtrace but I'd rather use a lighterweight mechanism if one exists. Any suggestions?

For example something like so, if you imagine the get_callee() function and constant existing:

```
function doSomething() {
     if(get_callee() == 'PHP_GLOBAL') { throw new IllegalAccessException(); }
     ...
}
```

Comment: No, don't think there is a built inn way to do it.

Comment: @Marius: Reflection? `debug_backtrace()`? There are ways.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Sorry, saw your note about debug_backtrace() now.**

Kinda ugly but hey, if you need to do this something is wrong.

The magic is in the get_callee() function and debug_backtrace(). And yes, add some error checking if you must use this.

```
<?php

init();

function foo()
{
 echo 'bar called from ' . get_callee() . '<br />';
 bar();
}

function bar()
{
 echo 'foo called from ' . get_callee() . '<br />';
}

function init()
{
 echo 'init.. <br />';
 foo();
}

function get_callee()
{
 $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
 return $backtrace[1]['function'];
}
```

**Outputs:**

> init..
>
> bar called from foo
>
> foo called from bar

Comment: Thanks, that's also what I had... but I don't want that overhead for each method call. What I'm trying to achieve is akin to the concept of friends - a way for composites to ensure that their public members are only accessed within the composite, hence there would be a check on every call. Never mind though - if anyone steps out of line I'll just beat them to death with a spade.

Comment: @Chocky yes, that is a much preferred solution, instead of doing this mess :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use OO and declare your method/function private?

If you start sprinkling those `get_callee()` all over your code, you are creating a horrible kludge.

Comment: @Anti Veeranna because I would require a common ancestor for unrelated classes. Say I have a User with some kind of UserHelper - they shouldn't have a common superclass but I'd need one to use member access to accomplish this.

Comment: Ok, I see. And you are not the first one to desire that feature .. sadly there is no clean way to do it in PHP :( This debug_backtrace thing is an evil hack.

Everything I have found about this is the commend at the end of http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37814

Answer (score 2):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) provides some nice functions.

```
<?php
  Class MyClass
  {
    function __construct(){
        $this->callee();
    }
    function callee() {
        echo sprintf("callee() called @ %s: %s from %s::%s",
            xdebug_call_file(),
            xdebug_call_line(),
            xdebug_call_class(),
            xdebug_call_function()
        );
    }
  }
  $rollDebug = new MyClass();
?>
```

will return trace

```
callee() called @ /var/www/xd.php: 16 from MyClass::__construct
```

To install Xdebug on ubuntu the best way is

```
sudo aptitude install php5-xdebug
```

You might need to install php5-dev first

```
sudo aptitude install php5-dev
```

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. However you should put the link(s) first I think to be visible enough...

Comment: @smarber I Updated my answer thanks for the feedback