# Get parent function within class

Tags: php

is following somehow possible? And if so how?!
I know i could pass a parameter but I'd like it to be dynamic!

```
<?php

class my_class {

  protected $parent = NULL;

  public function __construct() {

    // now i'd like to get the name of the function where this class has been called
    $this->parent = get_parent_function();

  }

  public function parent() {
    return $this->parent;
  }

}

function some_random_function() {
  // Do something
  $object = new my_class();

  print $object->parent(); // returns: some_random_function
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "parent," do you mean the class that `my_class` extends? Because that's trivial: `parent::get_parent_function`. But it sounds like you're after something different...

Comment: Looks like bad design. May i ask, Why you would like to do this?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc he's trying to get a reference to the function that is creating the object.

Comment: i'm trying to create a simple runtime cache class which uses the name of the function as key

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [How to get name of calling function/method in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php "How to get name of calling function/method in PHP?")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly this seems like a pretty bad design choice, however it would be possible to do this using call stack introspection using the PHP builtin `debug_backtrace` function. The following example is from the [php documentation for `debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php):

```
<?php
// filename: /tmp/a.php

function a_test($str)
{
    echo "\nHi: $str";
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

a_test('friend');
?>

<?php
// filename: /tmp/b.php
include_once '/tmp/a.php';
?>
```

If b.php is executed, the output could look like this:

```
Hi: friend
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    ["line"] => int(10)
    ["function"] => string(6) "a_test"
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0] => &string(6) "friend"
    }
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/b.php"
    ["line"] => int(2)
    ["args"] =>
    array(1) {
      [0] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    }
    ["function"] => string(12) "include_once"
  }
}
```

If you were clever you could use the function name of the function in the backtrace to call it, e.g. `debug_backtrace()[1]['function']()`, but this will only work if the function is defined in the scope that you are currently executing in. See the [php documentation on variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) for more info on calling functions by their name from a string.

In my opinion, though, there should be no reason for you to do this in a well designed program. Perhaps you should think about using objects and references to objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use (even if there probably are better designs):

```
public function __construct($functionname = NULL) {
    $this->parent = $functionname; 
}
```

Then just:

```
function some_random_function() {
  // Do something
  $object = new my_class('some_random_function');

  print $object->parent(); // returns: some_random_function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name of the function that called the constructor of `my_class`, you can use PHP's [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) as describe here:

[How to get name of calling function/method in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php)