# get function name that called function without arguments

Tags: php

I have a class `admin_model` with the private method `admin_form()`

There are a number of other public functions that call this method.

Is there a way to get the name of the function that called `admin_form()` from INSIDE `admin_form()`?

I could easily add an argument when calling `admin_form()` like:

```
$this -> admin_form(__FUNCTION__);
```

then inside `admin_form($caller)` I have the caller. It will be `$caller`

But i was hoping there was a way to do this WITHOUT passing arguments.

Any Ideas??

Cheers, 
Alex

Comment: means you want recursive function??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get name of calling function/method in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php)

Comment: There should be no real reason for you to do this, it indicates bad coding practises... but you might consider having namespaced functions if you need a function to do different things depending on where it's called from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter,

For my requirement this functionality is useful rather that 'bad coding'.

Anyway the answer is:

```
$e = new Exception();
$trace = $e -> getTrace();
$caller = $trace[1]["function"];
```

This will get the function name of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [debug_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php):

```
<?php
class admin_model {
    public function foo() {
        $this->admin_form();
    }

    public function bar() {
        $this->admin_form();
    }

    private function admin_form() {
        // Get the current call stack
        $stack = debug_backtrace();

        // Remove this call (admin_form()) from the stack
        array_shift($stack);

        // The calling method is now on the top of the stack
        $lastCall = array_shift($stack);
        $callingMethod = $lastCall['function'];

        echo "admin_form() called by method: $callingMethod\n";
    }
}

$model = new admin_model();
$model->foo();
$model->bar();
```

Output:

```
admin_form() called by method: foo
admin_form() called by method: bar
```

But, as others have pointed out, this is bad practice and you should rethink your design.