# How can I get the caller function name in my class?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get name of calling function/method in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php)

So in PHP I'm trying to build a custom error handler class. It's pretty simple:
I give it a code number and it gives back a formatted error message which I can use to send to mobile devices.

So it looks like this now:

```
class Errorhandler {
   private $errors = array(
       //here be error codes and messages
       100 => 'Missing input or parameter!'
  );

   public function __construct($code = 100){
        //return formatted output
   }
}
```

So I'd use the class above like:

```
public function someFunction(){
    //some conditions met, then throw an error
    $handler = new ErrorHandler();
    $this->response = $handler;        
}
```

So I'd need the parent function's name (someFunction) in my Errorhandler class so I can return it with the formatted error message.
On a side note: I don't want to use parameters for this, too much writing there.

Comment: Have you looked at the optional arguments for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 2):

`__FUNCTION__`

It's magic. See more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

As for actually getting it in your ErrorHandler class, you'd have to pass it to the constructor. PHP isn't *that* magical.

Comment: No, he meant the function that actually calls `__FUNCTION__`...

Comment: Wouldn't it be returning my custom errorhandler class's __construct() name?

Comment: `$handler = new ErrorHandler(__FUNCTION__);` ? Isn't that what you want? Then grab the function name in the `ErrorHandler` constructor and assign it to a class variable. Either that or use `debug_backtrace()` within the class itself.

Comment: Sadly no, because with this, I have to type in `__FUNCTION__` every time which is boring if you know what I mean.

Comment: so declare a global reference to it called `F` or something and pass that. Or just use `debug_backtrace()` which would be less messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debug_backtrace()` to get the function that have called your function.

`debug_backtrace()` returns the current call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `debug_backtrace()` function output. It returns associative array of all calls to the very top (http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Also notice that fatal error will interrupt normal script excution and to catch it you need to call error handler from callback registered with `register_shutdown_function()` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php)