# Get name function in PHP

Tags: php

I have some classes:

```
class A
{
   private $_method;
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->_method = new B();
   }
   public function demo()
   {
     $this->_method->getNameFnc();
   }
}

class B
{
   public function getNameFnc()
   {
     echo __METHOD__;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get the function name of a `class B` class, but I want the function `getNameFnc` to return 'demo'. How do I get the name 'demo' in function `getNameFnc` of `class B`?

Comment: So, you want to know which function *called* `getNameFnc()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get name of calling function/method in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php)

Comment: i want call name function demo in function getNameFnc

Comment: @Toàn: I'm a little confused here.  What is `getNameFnc` supposed to do?  Why does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to do this without passing a parameter*, you may use [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrage):

[→ Ideone.com](https://eval.in/88727)

```
public function getNameFnc()
{
  $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 2);
  echo $backtrace[1]['function'];
}
```

* this would be the recommended way although one should never need to know which function has been previously called. If your application relies on that fact, you have got a major design flaw.

Comment: +1 for the major design flaw. debug_backtrace should only be used for debugging purposes and not for application workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `debug_backtrace` to get that information.

I haven't tested the code below but I think this should give you the information you want:

```
$callers = debug_backtrace();
echo $callers[1]['function'];
```

Comment: It has to be `$callers[0]`, and you should also limit the backtrace using the second parameter.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong information in my last comment. Of course it is `1` and not `0`. Even my demo link was buggy, I can't believe that nobody corrected me ;)

Comment: haha no problem, I didn't have the time to test neither your code nor mine, so I just assumed yours was correct. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it?

```
class A
{
   private $_method;
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->_method = new B();
   }
   public function demo()
   {
     $this->_method->getNameFnc(__METHOD__);
   }
}

class B
{
   public function getNameFnc($method)
   {
     echo $method;
   }
}
```

Or use `__FUNCTION__` if you don't want the class name.

Comment: You have basically just created a wrapper for the `echo` function. It works, but is completely pointless.