# When chaining methods in PHP, Is it possible to determine which method was called first?

Tags: php, oop

So I am writing a PHP class at the moment to help make construction of SQL statements easier. I am writing them so that each method returns an instance of the object (`return $this`) in order to enable method chaining.

Is it possible to test whether a method being called is a part of a method chain and which methods have been executed already in the method chain? For example, in the below code, I would like the 'from' method to test whether it was called as part of a chain with the `select()` method directly before it.

`$object->select('john', 'chris')->from('people');`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not by default, but you could have implement a list in your object that each method would add itself to and you could review the chain as it's built.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/) . You may be able work out what you need using [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: You may implement that, but you should ask yourself if that's really a good idea: normally only the state of the object should matter and not what methods have been called and in which order

Comment: It's indeed possible to retrieve de call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to check sequence of called methods. You can create one finally method (for example `execute()` ), and in it check all attributes you needed for query, if any attribute is missing (for example `select`) you can set default value for it: if available(for example `'select' => '*'`).

But in any case if you want to check is some method called before concrete method, you can set `private` attribute to keep methods requirements. For example:

```
private $_methodsRequirements = array(
    'from' => array('select'),
    'set' => array('update', 'where'),
    // and all requiriments for each method
)
private $_calledMethods = array();
```

and create additional method for checking methods "callability":

```
private function checkCallability($method) {
    $requiredMethods = $this->_methodsRequirements[$method];
    foreach($requiredMethods as $m) {
        if(!in_array($m, $this->_calledMethods)) {
            throw new Exception('You must call method "'.$m.'" before calling method "'.$method.'"!');
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

and on begin of each method you must call it:

```
public function select() {
   $this->checkCallability(__METHOD__);
   // your query generation
   array_push($this->_calledMethods, __METHOD__);
}
```