# Method chaining, which is run first?

Tags: method-chaining

This is not a duplicate of [When chaining methods in PHP, Is it possible to determine which method was called first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289475/when-chaining-methods-in-php-is-it-possible-to-determine-which-method-was-calle)

---

I wonder if there is a general rule for the order of execution in method chaining? When running the following code:

```
obj.method1().method2();
```

Which is run first: `method1()` or `method2()`?

I assume `method1()` must necessary be called before `method2()`. Otherwise, since `method1()` is not already called, `method2()` has no returned object to process. Here is an experimental confirmation for JavaScript : http://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/sjo9gxfq/60/

But, I found an example against the previous statement with D3.js, where the objects seems selected before being created:

```
d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('p')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('p')
    .text('Paragraph');
```

**Which is called first?**

Comment: Methods are ran in order of left to right.

Comment: OK, thank you. Thus, how do you explain the last example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are called from left to right.

D3.js is a particular case, this article explains nicely what happens: 
[Thinking with Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948802/m%c3%a9thod-chaining-which-is-run-first?noredirect=1#comment106017415_59948802)