# Get parent __FUNCTION__ from inside child function

Tags: php

Is there any way (dirty is fine, this is only for debugging) to get the `__FUNCTION__` (function name) from where a function was called from?

example;

```
function a() {
    //code
    return b();
}

function b() {
    return __PARENT_FUNCTION__
}

echo a();
```

This should yield `a` as the function name that was originally called for this output

Comment: At the minute i'm just passing `__FUNCTION__` as a parameter to the 'child' function, it would be nice if I could do it automatically though

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

```
function a() {
    //code
    return b();
}

function b() {

    return debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)[0]["function"];
}

echo a();
```

Comment: Perfect, although I modified it slightly to `debug_backtrace()[1]['function'];` as it is in the [duplicate linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php)