# How to get CLASS/METHOD name, In which the function is called

Tags: php

I have a 'view.php' file like this and i have a `render()` method in it.

```
class view {

    public function render(){
        require 'views/header.php';
        require "views/??/??.php";// ??/?? should be name of class/ method in which render() method is called , is their some property for that like get_class or something else. in below 'home.php' ??/?? should be home/index.
        require 'views/footer.php';
    }
}
```

and i have a controller `home.php` like this.

```
<?php
class home{
    public $view;

    function __construct{   
        $this->view = new view;  
    }

    public function index(){              
        $this->view->render();// in this case ??/?? should be home/index
    }
}
?>
```

I want to get the name of the class and method  in which `render()` method is been called. For example I try in  render() method   `get_class` but it didn't  work  because it will give the name of the class where the function is defined i.e in above example if i use ??= `get_class` it will give  class name `view`

Yes I can use arguments  in `render()`  but then in every controller i have to define the arguments, But is their any way so that i can do it without using arguments.? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caller function in PHP 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5)