# how to insert a unique number inside my php source code file using eclipse IDE?

Tags: php, eclipse, notepad++

I need a way to make eclipse IDE suggest a unique number among the current PHP file while I'm coding.

for example if I write somewhere in the code `"unique-inCode-Sign-1"` and elsewhere `"unique-inCode-Sign-2"`, I need the IDE to suggest for me the next unique number which is `"3"` , something like this image

---

[image]

I need to do this because when I prepare the file to record and log errors and events that might happen, I need a way to uniquely find an *in-code sign* that uniquely identify the piece of code that logged the error for later code debugging. I was doing that when I was using [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which suggests the string literals inside his autocomplete functionality. but I can't find a similar  feature in eclipse. and obviously I can't depend on my memory to remember the last number specially when I have more than 50 unique in-code signs in the source file.

I'm using [eclipse mars for PHP developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/mars2)

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with PHP, but have you considered instead calling an object that just increments and then prints your debug string with the number, perhaps [including your calling function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2110732/4541045).

Comment: @ti7 thanks for your time, but I need to produce a fixed **in-text** unique number inside the source file to record it -the  unique number- along with the error or the whatever I need to log, so when review the application logs I see which piece of code logged that error. I don't need to produce a run time unique number.