# Get caller function arguments

Tags: php, reflection

How can I get the current function's caller function's arguments?

Comment: If your using `debug_backtrace()`, this provides the arguments - *args array If inside a function, this lists the functions arguments.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function.

It generates a PHP backtrace, returning an array of associative arrays. One of the keys in those associative arrays is `'args'`. If called inside a function, this key basically contains the functions arguments list (as an array). If this is used inside an included file, this lists the included file name(s).

For eg (from [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)):

```
function a_test($str)
{
    echo "\nHi: $str";
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

a_test('friend');
```

It will output the following:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    ["line"] => int(10)
    ["function"] => string(6) "a_test"
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0] => &string(6) "friend"
    }
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/b.php"
    ["line"] => int(2)
    ["args"] =>
    array(1) {
      [0] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    }
    ["function"] => string(12) "include_once"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The topic you mentioned with your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133897/3224296

```
function GetCallingMethodName(){
    $e = new Exception();
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    //position 0 would be the line that called this function so we ignore it
    $last_call = $trace[1];
    print_r($last_call);
}

function firstCall($a, $b){
    theCall($a, $b);
}

function theCall($a, $b){
    GetCallingMethodName();
}

firstCall('lucia', 'php');
```