# How to see which class (controller, method..) call Model saving, updating, creating

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have several classes where I update the model. In the model I have created boot methods where I call some logic and in this logic I want to know which class is the initiator of the Model being updating or creating.

How can I find out this?

Comment: You can try to use [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get calls stack. Than search what was before your model calls.

Comment: @Tarasovych i have tried this method but in laravel this show a looot of data and function works very slowly.

Comment: [Also take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11238046/9506712)