# PHP, anyway to know what method/class called another?

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caller function in PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5)

I have some objects that extend one another, and calls various helper methods. I am wondering if there is a way to detect which method called another. here's an example:

```
class Foo {
   function whereAmICalled() {
      $calling_method = '' //would like to get func_caller here when code is executed
      $calling_class = '' //would like to get 'Bar' here when code is executed
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   function func_caller() {
       $this->whereAmIcalled();
   }
}

$bar = New Bar();
$bar->func_caller();
```

Comment: Something like debug_backtrace()? I'm not sure to understand what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Duplicate indeed, with the remark that needing this information usually indicates bad design, an almost fundamental OO principle is you shouldn't need nor care which function/class calls the current method.

Comment: If you have to know the caller, then pass this information to the callee instead of letting the callee wade through the debug backtrace

Comment: Unless it's for debugging/tracing purposes, you *really* shouldn't build this into your application. Changing the behaviour of a function based on who called it/where it was called from is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) like this:

```
class Foo {
   function whereAmICalled() {
     $trace = debug_backtrace();
     echo "Caller class: {$trace[1]['class']}, method: {$trace[1]['function']}";
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   function func_caller() {
       $this->whereAmIcalled();
   }
}
```

You can check the output using `var_dump`:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
var_dump($trace);
```