# Get function name of child class in parent class

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

I would like to have a base class with basic properties and functions, so I dont have to define them in all child classes.
I use php 5.3.3.

Is this impossible ?

```
class A {
  private $debug;
  private $var;
  protected function setVar($str) {
    $this->debug = 'Set by function `'. MAGIC_HERE .'` in class `'. get_called_class() .'`.';
    $this->var = $str;
    return true;
  }
  protected function getVar() {
    return $this->var;
  }
  protected function getDebug() {
    return $this->debug;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->doSomething();
  }
  public function doSomething() {
    $this->setVar('my string');
  }
}
$myobj = new B();
$myobj->getDebug();
// expected output "Set by function `doSomething` in class `B`."
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class A {
  private $debug;
  private $var;
  protected function setVar($str) {
    $this->debug = 'Set by function `'. MAGIC_HERE .'` in class `'. get_called_class() .'`.';
    $this->var = $str;
    return true;
  }
  protected function getVar() {
    return $this->var;
  }

  // Notice the public here, instead of protected //
  public function getDebug() {
    return $this->debug;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->doSomething();
  }
  public function doSomething() {
    $this->setVar('my string');
  }
}
$myobj = new B();
echo $myobj->getDebug();
// expected output "Set by function `doSomething` in class `B`."
```

You had just two small issues. `A::getDebug` needed to be public to be accessible from the outside and you forgot to output the return of `A::getDebug`.

Answer (score 0):

See the [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) function. Note this function is expensive, so you should disable those debug features in production.

Answer (score 0):

Is this no good for you?

I'm not running 5.3 locally, so I had to switch out get_called_class() but you could still use it. Should have made that clear, sorry.

```
class A {
  private $debug;
  private $var;
  protected function setVar($str, $class) {
    $this->debug = 'Set by function `` in class `'. $class .'`.';
    $this->var = $str;
    return true;
  }
  protected function getVar() {
    return $this->var;
  }
  public function getDebug() {
    return $this->debug;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->doSomething();
  }
  public function doSomething() {
    $this->setVar('my string', __CLASS__);
  }
}
$myobj = new B();
echo $myobj->getDebug();
```