# Can an included PHP file know where it was included from?

Tags: php

For example,

This is index.php

```
<?
require_once('header.php');
?>
```

Can header.php know it was included by index.php?

--EDIT--

I found a solution:

```
function backtrace_filename_includes($name){
    $backtrace_array=debug_backtrace();
    if (strpos($backtrace_array[1]['file'],$name)==false){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

header.php

```
<?
if (backtrace_filename_includes('index.php')) echo "index.php";
?>
```

Comment: If you need this function you probably have some design issues. I'm sure with better organizing your code this function is never needed.

Comment: Good solution, works perfect for me.

Comment: vbence never had to modify someone else's messy and labyrinthic code obviously.. it will happen some day :D thanks a lot for the solution!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While [`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) will contain the currently *executing* script, there is no way to determine from an included file which specific script caused the include.

This means that if `a.php` includes `b.php`, which includes `c.php`, `c.php` will have no way of knowing that `b.php` was the includer.  The best you can get is that `a.php` is the currently executing script.

---

Edit: Yup, my above answer is technically wrong -- you can use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to find the caller, even without functions, **up until PHP 5.4, which removes this functionality**.

a.php:

```
<?php
echo 'A';
include 'b.php';
```

b.php:

```
<?php
echo 'B';
include 'c.php';
```

c.php:

```
<?php
echo 'C';
print_r(debug_backtrace());
```

Output:

```
ABCArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /tmp/b.php
            [line] => 3
            [function] => include
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /tmp/a.php
            [line] => 3
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/b.php
                )

            [function] => include
        )

)
```

So while this works, you probably shouldn't use it.  **`debug_backtrace` can be a noticeable performance drag when used excessively.**

Comment: Technically a script could find out from where it's been included by using debug_backtrace(), but that's not advisable ;)

Comment: Hm, does that actually work when outside of a function call, though?  Will check in a few moments...

Comment: I've updated my post with results from `debug_backtrace`, which does work.

Comment: @LongEars, why is it not advisable?

Answer (score 10):

`get_included_files()` provides a stack of the files included, in the order they are included, which in my case gave me everything I needed.

Specifically, if you call `get_included_files()` within a file that has been included, that file's own file-path will be the most recent entry on the stack returned by `get_included_files()`, the one that included it is above that, etc.

The caveat is that files are only listed once, so if the same file is included more than once, only the first include will show up in the stack. For my purposes that wasn't an issue, but it definitely means this won't work in all cases.

Specific example: imagine the file 'test1.php' includes 'test_include.php'. The result of get_included_files() from the perspective of 'test_include.php' after loading test1.php in the browser are as follows (given, as you can see, that I've got an auto_prepend file, which in turn loads an autoloader).

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "/www/auto_prepend.php"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "/www/autoloader.php"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "/www/test1.php"
  [3]=>
  string(21) "/www/test_include.php"
}
```

So test_include.php only has to do a little array_pop'ing to figure out who included it.

Comment: Great first answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` should still point to file originally accessed, or you could set a variable before the require, eg:

```
$section = 'home';
require_once('header.php');
```

...

```
if ($section == 'home') {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
debug_print_backtrace();
```

Check PHP docu

Answer (score 2):

PHP tracks the file that does the including for you in the backtrace. With a little helper function you can get the filename that had the last include command:

```
/**
 * get filename that included this file
 *
 * @return string filename
 */
function include_by() {
    $bt = debug_backtrace(0);
    while ($b = array_shift($bt)) {
        if (in_array($b['function'], array('require', 'require_once', 'include', 'include_once'), 1)) {
            return $b['file'];
        }
    }
    throw new BadFunctionCallException('Not an include.');
}
```

Usage:

*main.php:*

```
<?php
include('sub.php');
```

*sub.php:*

```
<?php
echo basename(include_by()); # main.php
```

See as well a related usage of the backtrace: [Caller function in PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190421/367456).

Comment: Thanks! :) was able to find where the declaration was. +1 rep

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way in the web server environment: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` will show the original file that is called.

Universal way - `debug_backtrace()` will show you all previous steps of the execution, which will include calls to require/include functions.

Comment: @hakre logically the function `function include_by()` return wrong info when a.php include to b.php, b.php to c.php, ..., finaly who include the file `some_notification.php` ?? Really not is possible know who include `my_file.php`? this is a limitation of PHP or also Python, JAVA, ASP, ...