# Which file has called one other?

Tags: php

Is there any way to determine the file which has called one other. E.g.

#### FILE `one.php`:

```
include('two.php');
...
```

#### FILE `two.php`:

// This file do some stuff

I'm getting a 500 internal server error on `two.php` (*unexpected end of file in two.php*).

However, the file has not an unexpected EOF, so I'm guessing that the issue comes from the file `one.php`. The problem is that I don't know which is that file. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5204873/1938163

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an included PHP file know where it was included from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204830/can-an-included-php-file-know-where-it-was-included-from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem long time ago. The problem was a `<?` PHP opening tag.

Solved just replacing `<?` with `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

You dont care about what file is calling the other one, since PHP parses the file by itself, so the problem is in you second file.

Take a look at a few things:

- check if your php tags have spaces after and before, i.e, change `{?>` whith this `{ ?>` or `<?phpSOMETHING` with   `<?php SOMETHING`
- Update: if you dont have `short_open_tag` on, change any `<?` for `<?php`
- Also, carefully count all your curly braces `{` and `}` and check that everything is closed properly.
- Do the same with single `'` and double `"` coutes.

If you post the code of your file we can better help you out

Comment: Just wanted to post this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code (y)!

Comment: yeah, point 1 is the same, but at least there are these 3 things to check out

Comment: Thanks Carlos, you opened my mind. The issue was the `<?` tag.