# Find out the name of the function from which a function was called

Tags: php, function, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caller function in PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5)

Like this:

```
function foo(){
  do_something();
}

function do_something(){
  // How can I find out if this function was called from "foo" ?
}
```

Is this possible in PHP?

(Note that in my case the `do_something()` function is actually a class method)

Comment: I'll just throw this out, know it isn't what you are looking for, but why not just pass it in as an argument?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5

Comment: it's kind of complicated... But in essence I don't have any control over the foo() function. That function only accepts a callback as argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `debug_backtrace()` ([manpage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php))

Comment: its name sounds scary. Is it OK use that outside of a dev environment?

Comment: If you really have to use it, you can use it. But don't try to change the behaviour of the function depending on the caller function but on the arguments (i know there are situations where it's necessary to get the caller function)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace), which will let you access the call stack.

```
function do_something(){
   $trace = debug_backtrace();
   if($trace[1]['function'] == 'foo'){
      // called from foo
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Caller function in PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5)