# If function called internally

Tags: php, class, function, internal

Is there any way of identifying if a function was called from within the same class in PHP?
Besides using something like [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) ?

Update:

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
class Alex {
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->internal = false;
  }

  function a()
  {
    $this->internal = true;
    $this->b();
  }

  function b()
  {
    if($this->internal) 
      // ...
    else
      // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for general or one case solution? Do you need to provide list of functions and if they were called more than one time or check it for exact function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caller function in PHP 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5)

Comment: On case solution. I need to check if the function (when called), is called within the class (by another function) or from outside (as a method belonging to the controller)

Comment: What exacly do you want to achieve here? Does your code making troubles? Or you dont want to pass this extra parameter?

Comment: @aorcsik all the solutions rely on `debug_backtrace`, which I am already aware of

Comment: @360flowMichael The purpose of that, is to know what to return within the function. Because if it's called from outside (like `http://site.com/controller/method` I will have to return something different as if is called from within the class. But well, seams for now that the solution I use, it's the best for now

Comment: I know that you already mentioned `debug_backtrace`, but why are you against it? If you want to "trace" where a certain function/method is called from then that is the only place you can look at. There's nothing wrong with `debug_backtrace`. What worries me more is that you actually need functionality like that, but that's a different story

Comment: I'm not against it, I was just trying to see if any other ways (besides the 2 mentioned). Well, I guess I'll have to decide which one to use, and go for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'm not sure why you would want to do that; this kind of requirement is suspicious, and usually for good reason.

That said, you can make a `protected` clone of the `public` function with an additional parameter that tells you if the caller was internal or external, and make the `public` version defer to the `protected` implementation.

```
class Before
{
    public foo() { /* code here */ }
}

class After
{
    public foo() { $this->fooCore(false); }
    protected fooCore($calledFromInside = true) { /* code here */ }

    // At this point you should make sure that you never call $this->foo()
    // directly from inside class After
}
```

Comment: interesting work around, but no... this would just make things way to complicated. Tnx anyway

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work if you need to know if `__call` was invoked by the class itself, or externally.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  I solved a similar problem by having an extra optional parameter that passed a value when called from inside the class.

HTH  :)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to debug PHP for instance in NetBeans like you can see to [debugging in NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html). Also, you can find useful tools on[sseful PHP tools](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/20/50-extremely-useful-php-tools/), like Webgrind or Xdebug.

Comment: the `debug_backtrace` I've mentioned it... and on the live server, I don't have NetBeans...