# Manipulating passed arguments in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im not so experienced in php , Im using codeigniter to write my application , I have my own library and within my library there are three functions/methods that passes there arguments in one function which is in one of my models , my question is how will i manipulate/trick the method in my model to know exactly which function among the three in my library has passed the value and return the correct value ..

**1st function**

```
 public function id_exist ($id) {

      if(empty($id)) {
           return FALSE;
       }
      return $this->library_model->this_exist($id);
   }
```

**2nd function**

```
 public function group_exist($group) {

       if(empty($group)){

           return FALSE;
       } 

       return $this->library_model->this_exist($group);  

   }
```

with the 3rd same as the above 2

**in my model**

```
 public function this_exist ($item) {

              if(empty($item) || !isset($item)) {

                  return FALSE;

              }

         // here is where i need to know which function has passed the argument so that i can work with it and return the correct value from the database 


 }
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5

Comment: I kinda bumped into that question before posting this question . can you please illustrate or give out an example how i will trace methods from other classes using [debug_backtrace](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: There is a perfectly adequate example on that page. http://stackoverflow.com/a/190426/2812842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be dirty, might be not sophisticated, but why not passing another argument which tells exactly the origin?

```
public function id_exist ($id) {
      if(empty($id)) {
           return FALSE;
       }
      return $this->library_model->this_exist('id', $id);
   }

public function group_exist($group) {

       if(empty($group)){
           return FALSE;
       } 

       return $this->library_model->this_exist('group', $group);  
   }
```

Model:

```
public function this_exist ($origin, $item) {

  if(empty($item) || !isset($item)) {
       return FALSE;
  }

  if($origin == 'id'){
   // do something
  }
  elseif($origin == 'group') {
   // do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what i wanted .. using debug_backtrace will be a bit of a headache for me because i do not know exactly how it works .. thanx bro @Damien Pirsy