# How does __call() magic function exactly work in PHP?

Tags: php, magic-function

I have an object named $obj. I have overridden the `__call` function for that class, so that when I call `$obj->setVariableName($value)` then this happens: `$obj->variableName = $value`. I don't know when and how exactly `$obj->setVariableName($value)` is called in the project. So, during running the application this happens:

```
setVariable1($value) : works!
setVariable2($value) : works!
setVariable3($value) : It won't trigger __call()
setVariable4($value) : works!
```

And when I write the extra function `setVariable3`, then it works. I don't know how `setVariable3` is called, whether it is called directly by `$obj->setVariable3` or it is called with a function like `call_user_func_array`.

What the problem might be that `__call` is not working for `setVariable3`?

**Update:** Now I know that `setVariable3` is called from a `$form->bind($user)` and running `$user->setVariable3('foo')` works. (This is a ZF2+Doctrine project)

Comment: It can not be so. Also, why are you using `__call()` in such strange way? Setters (so `__set()`) is exactly the feature that you're looking for

Comment: `__set` is for the time that I want to run `$obj->variableName = $value`. In this case I don't have access to how its called. In fact in this case I know that somewhere in the code `$obj->setVariable3($value)` is called, and I need to define the function for it.

Comment: As you are unclear on where/how the variable is being set, the first port of call might be to investigate the calling code.  To help you identify the calling code use `debug_backtrace` function.

See - http://bd1.php.net/debug_backtrace.

Comment: `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` gave me a huge amount of data, I'm using ZF2+Doctrine

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy you should output only the caller by filtering the data or only the levels you are interested in - http://stackoverflow.com/a/190426/1603275

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange but works for me.

```
class test {
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        printf("Called %s->%s(%s)\n", __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, json_encode($args));
    }
}
$test = new test();
$value = 'test';
$test->setVariable1($value);
$test->setVariable2($value);
$test->setVariable3($value);
$test->setVariable4($value);
```

Will output:

```
Called test->__call(["test"])
Called test->__call(["test"]) 
Called test->__call(["test"]) 
Called test->__call(["test"])
```

And __set will only be called if you try to access unaccessible properties. e.g.

```
class test {
    public function __set($var, $value) {
        printf("Called %s->%s(%s)\n", __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, json_encode(func_get_args()));
    }
}
$test = new test();
$value = 'test';
$test->callMagicSet = $value;
```

will result in:

```
Called test->__set(["callMagicSet","test"])
```