# How to get vars of method php

Tags: php, oop, breadcrumbs

I want to create Auto breadcrumb as array contain sub arrays with 2 keys ( link, title ).
like this:

```
array (
    0 => array (
        'link' => 'index',
        'title' => 'Home :)',
    ),
    1 => array (
        'link' => 'advanced',
        'title' =>  'Advanced Setting :)'
    )
);
```

### Note

when i use the following code it give me this result but i cannot get the title as you can see on the variable `$mytitle`.

```
class Setting extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $relflection = new ReflectionClass ( get_class ( $this ) );
        $methods = $relflection->getMethods ( ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC );
        if (is_array ( $methods )) {
            foreach ( $methods as $method ) {
                if ($method->class == get_class ( $this )) {
                    $breadcrumb[] = array("link" => $method->name, "title" => "???");
                }
            }
        }
        $breadcrumb = $breadcrumb;
    }

    public function index() {
        $mytitle = "Home :)";
    }

    public function advanced() {
        $mytitle = "Advanced Setting :)";
    }
}
```

Can anyone here give me a right solution for this?

Comment: call index() and return the title in that function

Comment: the method will have functionality and will return something else.

Comment: `"title" => $relflection->getMethod($method->name)->invoke()`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not wildly far from your need, but this could work:

first assign your breadcrumb to an actual property, or it won't be accessible out of your constructor's scope:

```
$this->breadcrumb = $breadcrumb;
```

then from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5/190426#190426) question you can devise a way to get your function name:

```
function getMyCallerName() {
  $array = debug_backtrace();
  return $array[1]['function'];
} 
// since you call a function to have your function name, the right caller will be the second function in the backtrace
```

you need a function to get the desired title from your breadcrumbs:

```
function getTitleFromLink($link) {
  foreach ($this->breadcrumb as $array) {
  if ($array['link'] == $link) return $array['title'];
  }
}
```

then you can use it in your `index()` function:

```
public function index() {
  $title = getTitleFromLink(getMyCallerName()); // should be "Home :)"
}
public function advanced() {
  $title = getTitleFromLink(getMyCallerName()); // should be "Advanced Setting :)"
}
```

you can then add any logic you wish in your index function

be sure to put those function in your class or `getTitleFromLink()` will not be able to use the `breadcrumb` property